# Date and Time filter for Ext Js

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

How to incorporate date along with time filter in Ext Js ? I got normal date filter which help me to filter the date but I want to filter time too. Please give me suggestion if there is any plug-in which have date time calender then this will be a fantastic solution.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?22661-new-version-DateTime-Field